# angularjs controller members undefined after promise returns

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a method in a controller which executes the following code:

```
this.StockService.GetByInvoicesID(this.SelectedInvoice.ID).success((StockItems) =>
{
    this.StockItems = StockItems;
    this.CreditNoteStockItems = new Array<ViewModels.CreditNoteStockItemViewModel>();
}
```

Before this service method is called, all members in the controller are defined. However, once the promise resolves, this.StockItems and this.CreditNoteStockItems are all undefined. Furthermore, the assignment of StockItems is not being reflected in the view. I'm guessing this is a scope issue and the promise is returning into a new scope. This has happened with other methods before, it almost seems to happen at random.

My questions are, can anyone tell me why exactly this is happening, and more importantly, how can I prevent it from occurring?

edit: This is a simplified version of my controller (all thats missing is several members and methods)

edit 2: more info about method in controller

```
export class CreditNoteController
{
    static $inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'StockService'];

    StockService: Services.StockService;
    ModalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance;

    constructor($scope, $modalInstance, StockService: Services.StockService)
    {
        $scope.vm = this;

        this.ModalInstance = $modalInstance;
        this.StockService = StockService;
    }

    InvoicesSelectionChanged()
    { 
        this.StockService.GetByInvoicesID(this.SelectedInvoice.ID).success((StockItems) =>
        {
            this.StockItems = StockItems;               
            this.CreditNoteStockItems = new Array<ViewModels.CreditNoteStockItemViewModel>();              

        });            
    }
}
```

The controller is injected through the angular UI modal service open method sitting in another controller:

```
this.ModalService.open(
{
    templateUrl: URL,
    controller: Controllers.CreditNoteController,
               });
```

edit 2: The javascript that it generates

```
CreditNoteModalController.prototype.InvoicesSelectionChanged = function () {
    var _this = this;                      

    this.StockService.GetByInvoicesID(this.SelectedInvoice.ID).success(function (StockItems) {
             _this.StockItems = StockItems;                        
             _this.CreditNoteStockItems = new Array();                       
         });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: `this` is probably not what you think it is inside the success handler

Comment: could you show how you define and use this controller?

Comment: I have added more info about the controller in my post.

Comment: @charlietfl, TypeScript redefines code refering to `this` within arrow function expressions. When translated to JavaScript TypeScript will add a declaration `var _this = this` before the call and then the arrow function becomes `_this.StockService` which should work.

Comment: Please post more of `CreditNoteController`. How exactly does the above code go inside `CreditNoteController` ?  If you put it exactly as stated above in the position stated you'll end up with invalid TypeScript. It needs to be wrapped in a method.  Please also post the relevant generated JavaScript. Does `this` get translated to `_this` like it's supposed to?

Comment: I added the method to the controller shown as well as the javascript it generates, and yeah it looks like its doing the correct thing with _this

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you inspecting the values of this.StockItems and this.CreditNoteStockItems to see them undefined? Are you using a debugger or dumping them via console.log or some similar mechanism?

Comment: I'm using the debugger in Visual Studio.

Comment: When your breakpoint gets hit can you create a watch on _this and see if it shows the same undefined values for your properties?

Comment: Okay, what I did was placed two breakpoints, one before the call to the promise and one after. Before the call both this and _this equated to the same thing, afterwards however, the _this in the js file was perfectly fine and had all the members of the controller, but the this in the ts file was pointing to, I dont even know what, it had all sorts of members, perhaps the global scope?

Comment: Ok, so basically the debugger is resolving this to probably the global scope. Good news is that it sounds like your _this is setup correctly, and that it's just the debugger giving you trouble. The other problem is probably related to something in your view. Did you include the vm. prefix in your bindings? May need to provide some snippets of your view if you want more help here.

Comment: Yeah this is confusing the hell out of me, the binding for the list of stock items in the view is: ng-options="SI.Name for SI in vm.StockItems" inside of a select tag. I don't see any problem with that though.

Comment: Couple of other things to try. Do you have an ng-model="xxx" attribute on your <select> as well? ng-options won't work without it. If this isn't the problem, you may also want to try setting your StockItems array with some mock data just inside of your controller constructor to rule out any scoping issues that occur inside of the promise return.

Comment: Sigh, okay it was the ng-model, I didnt have that in the tag. Thanks dude, wanna go put this as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth in the comment thread, turns out there were 2 things going on here, so consolidating the info into the answer:

1. When inspecting 'this' in a debugger in a .ts file, know that you will be seeing the actual 'this' value and not the _this alias that is created in the .js file when you use arrow functions. This can sometimes make it look like variables aren't getting set when in reality, you are inspecting the wrong variable. Setting a watch on _this will show the right one. You also have the option of using console.log on 'this' in the TypeScript code itself, since it will compile to using the _this alias.
2. ng-options won't work without ng-model